# XML AppendChild not writing to the xml file when used in a loop

Tags: c#, xml

I'm writing an application that takes the data from several different XML files and moves them into one. However when I try to do this, it writes nothing. My code is as follows:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xsh);
XmlElement dataElm = xdoc.CreateElement(@"rs:data");
string contents = "";
foreach (var i in Numbers.GetWSnumber())
{
    string curFile = @"\\wwproduction02\public2\Software\PMStatus\Status\WS" + i.WeaverSetId + ".xml";
    if (File.Exists(curFile))
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(curFile);
        while ((contents = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            dataElm.InnerText = contents;
            xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(dataElm);
        }
    }
}
xdoc.Save("doc.xml");
```

The format for the XML I'm trying to achieve is

```
<xml> 
<Schema> 
schema data in here 
</Schema> 
<rs:data> 
XML from other files here 
</rs:data> 
</xml>
```

The Schema is fine and being handled by something else.
Any help is appreciated with this. Thank you.

Comment: [Use the Debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging)

Comment: Perhaps try creating a new `XmlElement` inside the `while` block. From inspection, it looks like you are just overwriting the `InnerText` value each time.

Comment: Creating dataElm should be done in the inner loop.

Comment: Most likely, you overwrites inserted child with latest content (you use same object all the time) and at the end it's content could be equal to EOF

Comment: I have, I step through the code and the contests of each line of each xml file pass through contents and the 'dataElm.' If it helps, what's in 'contents is data from an xml file.

Comment: @Dima Is there another way to do this then?
Richard Schneider: I can't put it in the loop because I need all of these to be in one <rs:data> tag.

Comment: @Danger_Fox please share xml structure you're trying to achieve

Comment: <xml>
<Schema>
schema data in here
</Schema>
<rs:data>
XML from other files here
</rs:data>
</xml>

Comment: when posting your code Danger_Fox, post it in the Question section not the comments section, it's easier to read that way

Comment: Added the XML format to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is single step your code under a debugger to see what it is doing. Chances are that it is not finding any data to process. (For example, Numbers doesn't return anything, curFile doesn't exist, or curFile doesn't contain any lines of data). Or perhaps the program is throwing an exception long before it even tries to process anything.

Use a debugger to check that your code is doing what you assume it will do.

You are also appending a *reference* to an XML element to your document.
Then you change its InnerText, and re-add the *same* reference, so the document could well be ignoring you.

Try creating a new XMLElement each time you need one, rather than re-using a single one. i.e. do all of this together in the inner block:

```
XmlElement dataElm = xdoc.CreateElement(@"rs:data");
dataElm.InnerText = contents;
xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(dataElm);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything glaring, but my immediate thought/suspicion is that you are not locating your XML files on disk.  Try adding an else clause and logging out (via log4net or some other means) a statement that the current file was not found, as such:

```
if (File.Exists(curFile))
{
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(curFile);
    while ((contents = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        dataElm.InnerText = contents;
        xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(dataElm);
    }
}
else 
{
    // log statement that file curFile was not found
}
```

**UPDATE**

You are not closing your `System.IO.StreamReader`.  Although I do not believe this is causing your problem, you definitely do not want to leave I/O readers unclosed.

You will want to call [System.IO.StreamReader.Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.close.aspx)

Comment: It is locating the files, when I step through the code it's finding the files and getting the data from them.

Comment: Danger_Fox look at your code and notice this line `System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(curFile);` are you wanting to create a new Stream in the Outer Loop everytime..? if not then your line of code is `Wrong` you will be creating a new Instance everytime.. why not try what Philip Tenn has suggested ..it looks to be more correct than what you are trying to do..

Comment: @DJKRAZE, @Danger_Fox, Thanks for the input.  One thing I definitely noticed that is wrong is the `System.IO.StreamReader` is never closed.

Comment: You should also do the following you should call `file.Flush();, File.Close();` and `((IDisposable)file).Dispose()`; do some proper cleanup

Comment: I tried Phillip's code and it gave me the files that don't exist, but they are known files that aren't there because the SP I call is slightly out of date. When it hits the nonexistant files though it moves on.